# Estimation mean and variance of truncated normal distribution with rjags

Tags: r, bayesian, truncation, jags

I would like to estimate the population mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution which is truncated at a particular value. More specific, I want to get these estimates of the untruncated distribution by using the truncated distribution.

I used the `rjags` package for doing this, but I get estimates which are not even near to the population mean and standard deviation. As a consequence, I probably made a mistake but I have no idea what the mistake is. Below is the code:

```
library(rjags)

sigma <- 1 # Standard deviation in population

y <- qnorm(seq(1/101, 1/101*100, 1/101), mean = 0, sd = sigma) # Observed scores
y <- y[y > 0] # Truncated scores
k <- length(y) # Number oberved effect sizes which are left after truncation

### Model
modelstring <- "
model
{
  for(i in 1:k){
        y[i] ~ dnorm(mu,prec)T(0, )
    }
    mu ~ dnorm(0,.001)
    sigma ~ dunif(0,100)
    prec <- 1/(sigma*sigma)
  }
"

### Running jags
model <- jags.model(textConnection(modelstring),
                   data = list('y' = y,
                               'k' = k),
                   n.chains = 4,
                   n.adapt = 1000)

update(model, 10000)

jags.samples(model,
             c('mu', 'sigma'),
             10000)
```

Convergence seems to be ok and using more informative prior distributions does also not really help.

Note that this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552737/truncated-normal-distribution-in-rjags is related but the question is not answered.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are not being coherent. `y` is a vector of quantiles, while it should be a random vector (obtained through `rnorm` and not `qnorm`). For instance `y<-rnorm(k,0,sigma)`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, if it does not work with quantiles it will also definitely not work with random numbers.

Comment: Replace `T(0,)` with `T(mu,)` to actually reproduce the model with which you generated the data.

Comment: OK, thanks that looks better w.r.t. the estimates!. Can you maybe explain the rationale why it works when the truncation is T(mu,)? This is somewhat counterintuitive in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't specify the constraint of the distribution being a half-normal (i.e. truncation at its mean), then other truncated normals fit quite well (specifically, that with mean=0.8 and sd=0.6). This might help visualise what's going on: `curve(ifelse(x > 0, dnorm(x, 0.8, 0.6), 0), -0.5, 3, n=10000); abline(v=c(0, 0.8), lwd=3, col=c('#00000030', '#ff000030')); points(y, jitter(rep(0, k)), pch=20, cex=0.8, col='#00000050')`.

Comment: OK, thank you. How can I specify via the T( , ) that, for instance, only 25% of the highest scores of the normal distribution were observed? Thus, I generate my data via: `y <- qnorm(seq(1/101, 1/101*100, 1/101), mean = 0, sd = 1) # Observed scores
y <- y[75:100]
`

Comment: The quantile you're talking about is roughly located at `mu + 0.674*sigma`, so you can try `T(mu+0.674*sigma, )`. You'll need to set appropriate initials for both parameters, and it'll take longer to converge.